# How can I use this api? Keep getting error with mime type...(naver smart editor error)

Tags: javascript, html, api, mime-types

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="../../Api/se2/js/service/huskyESCreator.js"></script>
<textarea cols="102" rows="30" class="writing" name="contents" id="contents" style="resize: none;" placeholder="Write Your Contents"></textarea>
<script>
$(function(){
        nhn.husky.EZCreator.createInIFrame({
            oAppRef : oEditors,
            elPlaceholder : "contents",
            sSkinURL : "../../Api/se2/SmartEditor2Skin.html",
            fCreator : "createSEditor2",
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is my code.
This is my first time using api and getting error with using Naver's smart editor API. I'm using chrome and getting console error like 404(../../Api/se2/js/service/huskyESCreator.js) and MIME TYPE error.
How can I fix this?